# Makes downloads go to Word

Tags: windows-7, firefox, download

Every time I try to download it goes to Word and will not open up up the file. I am using Firefox as my browser. I have gone to `Options > Applications` to make the correct changes.

Comment: try right click and select save link as / download. ( Sorry not sure about firefox settings)

Comment: What type of file are you trying to download?

Comment: When you went to Options > Applications, can you explain what you did, or tried to do?

Comment: Some types of files can't be opened within Firefox by asking Firefox to launch the application and pass the file.  MS Office files are among those.  You might find a browser-resident viewer, but associating the file extension in Firefox with Word won't work.  You need to save the file to your hard disk and then open it outside of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to reset your file extension association defaults. On windows this can be achieved by:

1. Open the Control Panel (icons view), and click on the Default Programs icon.
2. Click on the Set your default programs link.
3. In the left column, select (highlight a listed program that you want to change it's default file associations for.
4. To Set the Program as the Default Program for All of it's Associations 
   A) Click on Set this program as default. (See screenshot below step 3A)
   B) Go to step 6.
5. To Manually Choose Default Associations to be Associated with the Program
   A) Click on Choose defaults for this program. (See screenshot below step 3A)
   B) Check the file extensions you want this program to be associated to open by default. NOTE: These are the default settings for each listed default program. You will only be able to uncheck the file extenstions that you just checked and were not already checked before doing step 5A.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

> If you're having problems with Firefox, refreshing it can help. The
>   refresh feature fixes many issues by restoring Firefox to its default
>   state while saving your essential information like bookmarks,
>   passwords, and open tabs.